# How can I clear the CoreBluetooth cache on MacOS?

Tags: macos, core-bluetooth

I'm developing a Bluetooth LE device and am having trouble because of MacOS's caching of the services.  If I try to delete a service or change its UUID on the device I'm developing, the change doesn't show up on the Mac and instead I continue seeing the old list of services and UUIDs from the device.  I tried going to another Mac that hadn't paired with my device and it saw the new list of services with the correct UUIDs, so it seems to be a caching issue with my development Mac.

I found the com.apple.Bluetooth.plist file in /Library/Preferences and deleted it, but the system put it back with the same data, I presume the system has the cache loaded into memory and is just writing it back out when needed.

Does anybody know how to wipe the MacOS CoreBluetooth device/service cache?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I finally found the source of the problem -- there's a cache in the user preferences folder in a folder named ByHost.  Here are the steps to clear the Bluetooth cache:

- Turn off Bluetooth
- Delete com.apple.Bluetooth.plist from
  /Library/Preferences
- Delete files named
  com.apple.Bluetooth.somehexuuidstuff.plist from
  ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost (note that this is the user preference
  folder, not the system one)
- Turn on Bluetooth

After doing that my peripheral's services are correctly identified.  From what I found on the web, there may also be some other com.apple.Bluetooth files in /Library/Preferences related to HIDs or headsets or something -- I don't know if it's important to delete those as I didn't have them on my system.

Comment: I've run into this issue a lot on my devices. For iOS (not OSX), I've found that on iOS, it's sufficient about 80-90% of the time to simply turn the BT off and on to eliminate the caching problems. The other 10-20%, I do a device restart, and it works.

Comment: Every update to El Capitan 10.11.x has required me to delete the "ByHost" plist files for Bluetooth to work again, but I have to reboot first.

Comment: Tried this with Sierra and when I turn bluetooth back on, the 19950 items in CoreBluetoothCache are still in the newly created com.apple.Bluetooth.plist

Comment: This solved a problem where my 16" MacBook Pro running Big Sur kept reconnecting to a bluetooth speaker device. This was the only way I found that could remove the device permanently.

Comment: Update: It didn't actually solve the problem. What ended up solving it was downloading a legacy version of Bluetooth Explorer from the Mac developer's portal, and disabling "Simple Pairing". After that, it seems the device would actually ask before each pairing. I could then check "ignore this device". After this, it seems the continuous auto pairing from the device has stopped. What a mess, Apple's software quality has really gone downhill lately.

Answer (score 0):

You can also clear the cache via the following command in the Terminal:

`sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist && sudo shutdown -r now`

This does what John explained earlier; make sure you have no ongoing / unsaved processes taking place (since this command will restart your machine).