# When does iOS display "need to bond" dialog?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I am writing an iOS app that communicates with a BLE device that we are developing.  Most communication does not require bonding, but there are some secure features where bonding will be required.  I've put those secure features in a separate service which has been flagged as requiring bonding, and when I try to access that service iOS correctly starts the bonding process.

The problem I'm having, is that I want to be able to control exactly when this bonding takes place so I can design my UI appropriately.  Most of the time, iOS waits until I try to access the secure service before it starts the bonding process, but I have also seen the bonding dialog appear shortly after I call CBPeripheral.DiscoverCharacteristics() and long before I actually use the secure service for anything.  The bonding dialog seems to appear later if I'm re-running the app when I've already bonded once and then deleted the bonding both in iOS and the remote BLE device.

I'm guessing that iOS is caching the service/characteristic information, so after the first connection when I call CBPeripheral.DiscoverCharacteristics() it's not actually communicating with the remote BLE device, and thus isn't triggering the need to bond.

There's a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553957/how-can-i-clear-the-corebluetooth-cache-on-macos) about how to clear the bluetooth cache on OSX, but nothing similar for iOS.  I've tried this:

1. Unbond device in iOS
2. Turn off Bluetooth
3. Turn off iPad
4. Turn iPad back on
5. Turn Bluetooth back on

But the bonding request dialog still comes later, which I'm guessing means the cache didn't actually get cleared.

Answer (score 1):

If the devices are unbonded and the peripheral sends an SMP "Security Request", it will show the popup.

It also shows it when you try to interact with a protected characteristic.